# org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets, spring-security

I'm building a app using spring MVC and spring security, when i type username and password i can't navigate to the next page (index). This is my code, please help me.

spring-servlet

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.AppFirst.controller"/>

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven />
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

```
<display-name>AppFirst</display-name>



<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml
        /WEB-INF/security-context.xml
    </param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>
</web-app>
```

LoginController.java

```
@Controller
```

public class LoginController {

```
@RequestMapping("/login")
public String doLogin(){
    return "login";
}
```

}

Comment: Add <mvc:annotation-driven /> in your spring-servlet.xml

Comment: i changed my spring-servlet schema.....but it didn't works i add <mvc:annotation-driven/>
this is the error WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/AppFirst/index] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add **"`<mvc:annotation-driven/>`"** in your spring-servlet.xml
Also, as the error suggests, you need to check if the URL you are having the problem, is mapped to a controller with `@RequestMapping`

Comment: i changed my spring-servlet schema.....` but it didn't works i add
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

Comment: this is the error
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/AppFirst/index] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'

Comment: Do you have a controller that is mapped to the URI /AppFirst/index?

Comment: No, i'm doing the redirect using spring security:
<http use-expressions="true">
  <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
  <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/index" authentication-failure-url="/login"/>
  <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/index"/>
 </http>

Comment: Hi, in anycase, unless you have a controller that is mapped for /index , you will get this error, try creating a method and map it like @RequestMapping("/index"), it should work